# Placing a horizontal helper in Constraint Layout to be at the bottom of a View with a set custom margin

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

How do I set it so that a horizontal helper in `Constraint Layout` is set to be at the bottom of a particular `View` with a margin of `16dp` in between?

What I've tried (with horizontal `Guideline`):

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.30779755"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view2" />
```

It doesn't actually care about the `layout_marginTop` and `layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf` attribute. If I erase the `layout_constraintGuide_percent` attribute, it goes haywire and sticks to the top of the parent.

**EDIT**

I created that `Guideline` because I have a `View` which acts as a "background" behind **multiple** `Views`. I was hoping to constrain this background `View` to the bottom of this `Guideline` with an offset of 16dp from the last vertically aligned `View` (from the multiple `Views`). I want this background `View` to have a height based on the last vertically aligned `View` from the multiple `Views`, i.e. the height is determined by the bottom of the view + a 16dp margin. If I constrain the bottom of said background `View` to the bottom of the last vertically aligned `View` and add a bottom margin, the background `View` instead retracts 16dp from the bottom of the last vertically aligned `View`.

Comment: What you are seeing is the correct behavior. Helpers don't generally adhere to margins. Placement for guidelines are based on percentages or a fixed distance. Do you need such a guideline? Why not just constrain to the bottom of the view with 16dp margin?

Comment: @Cheticamp I see. Yes, I do need that guideline because I have a `View` which acts as a "background" behind *multiple* `Views`. I want this background `View` to have a height based on the last vertically-aligned `View` from the multiple `Views`, i.e. the height is determined by the bottom of the view + a 16dp margin. If I constrain the bottom of said background `View` to the bottom of the last vertically-aligned `View` and add a bottom margin, the background `View` instead retracts 16dp from the bottom of the last vertically-aligned `View`.

Comment: Makes sense. With ConstraintLayout 2.0 you can set a background to your view with a [_Layer widget_](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/helper/widget/Layer) and set the bottom padding to `16dp`. You can't constrain other views to this layer widget but, if it's just a background, that won't matter. Otherwise, you can place a space widget with a top margin of `16dp` and constrain its top to the bottom of the bottom-most view. The background view can then be constrained to the top of the space view which will give you a `16dp` margin.

Comment: @Cheticamp Wow, I didn't know about the layer widget. But I did more research yesterday and found out about the `Space` widget. Would you like to provide the full answer below (perhaps with the implementation(s) too)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a [*Space widget*](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Space) with a height of `16dp` and a top constrained to the bottom of the lowest view. The bottom of the background view can be constrained to the bottom of the *Space* view to visually create the margin as follows using `64dp` to accentuate the margin:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/space"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/view1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/view1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="Using a Space widget"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="view2"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view1" />

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/space"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view2" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

I also mentioned using a [*Layer helper*](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/helper/widget/Layer) with a bottom padding of `16dp`. Although this currently works with *ConstraintLayout 2.0.0-beta3*, I am not convinced that it should work, so use at your discretion. Here is how it looks again with a *Layer* using `64dp` padding to accentuate the margin. You will need *ConstraintLayout* 2.0 or later.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Layer
        android:id="@+id/layer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:paddingBottom="64dp"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="view2,view1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Using a Layer"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="view2"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view1" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have accepted your answer.